# How do I set if condition for sprite renderer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to have an if condition to do something if the sprite renderer of another object is enabled, but it won't work.

Here's the code I tried:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUpReCharge : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Animator anim;
    public Animator animc;
    public Animator anime;
    public GameObject neon;
    public GameObject chargesprite;
    public AudioSource recharge;
    public BoxCollider2D collision;
    public SpriteRenderer blackout;
    public AudioSource ambient;
    public AudioSource music;

    void Start()

    {
        anime.Play("Pickup", 0, 1f);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {

            neon.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().enabled = true;
            chargesprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
            collision.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
            anim.SetBool("IsDead", false);
            anim.Rebind();
            animc.Rebind();
            anime.Rebind();
            recharge.Play();
            Destroy(gameObject, 3.0f);

            //activate blackout
            blackout.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;


            if (blackout.enabled)
            {
                ambient.Play();
                music.Play();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The public blackout has a sprite renderer that is disabled. When enabled, I want the last bit of code to run but it won't.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: blackout.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false; you set it to false before the last if statement

Comment: `blackout` already **is** the `SpriteRenderer` so doing `blackout.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>()` does absolutely nothing => `blackout.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;` equals `blackout.enabled = false;` => it will never be true after that line

Comment: did you try gameobject.activeSelf ?

Answer (score 0):

Prodian asked if I tried gameobject.activeself, and I want to thank you for the advice. It works perfectly! I changed the reference type to gameobject and reaasigned it and made the necessary and it works like a charm now!

Here's the full new code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUpReCharge : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Animator anim;
    public Animator animc;
    public Animator anime;
    public GameObject neon;
    public GameObject chargesprite;
    public AudioSource recharge;
    public BoxCollider2D collision;
    public GameObject blackout;
    public AudioSource ambient;
    public AudioSource music;

    void Start()

    {
        anime.Play("Pickup", 0, 1f);
    }

    void Update()

    {



    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {

            neon.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().enabled = true;
            chargesprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
            collision.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
            anim.SetBool("IsDead", false);
            anim.Rebind();
            animc.Rebind();
            anime.Rebind();
            recharge.Play();
            Destroy(gameObject, 3.0f);



            if (blackout.gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                ambient.Play();
                music.Play();
            }

            blackout.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: One more thing to note! The location of the if statement WAS important. It should have been before the code that makes the sprite false. This means the previous code would've worked if that had been done, but the gameobject code is much better for me because the blackout layer is one that I need to be OFF all the time.

Basically, my old code works! Just move the if statement before the "getcomponent......enabled = false" because the script is read in order.

Answer (score 0):

Your `blackout` is `SpriteRenderer` so calling `GetComponent` on it is invalid. Change that to:

```
blackout.enabled = true;
```

Or use:

```
anotherGameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
```

---

Calling `SetActive` on a GameObject will disable not only the `SpriteRenderer` component! In some cases this changes your desired behaviour.